# How to get rid of a mouse from home

Tags: home, pest-control

Please suggest possible remedies for mouse entering the house.

Does ultrasonic repellent work? Please share your experience.

Do home remedies work?

Comment: Related and probably duplicate: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/4371/6973 or https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/2338/6973 or https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/7445/6973

Comment: @Chenmunka Thank you for the links. I checked the threads. Trapping the mouse sounds difficult. The mouse looks quite smart and used to escaping.

Comment: Borrow a cat? ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to have a mouse problem where I lived. Tried mousetraps, ultrasonics, being super clean, home remedies but the only thing that worked was to find their escape routes. You must block ALL holes in your house. Check along all the walls behind furniture, any chimneys, in cupboards. You may have to consult a professional exterminator to help you locate them. Also if you chase the mouse it will often show you the hole it came from.

Comment: Thank you @MotherBrain. Tried closing its route. Still it came again. Don't know how.

Comment: @mohinip the little bugger! Are you sure it’s the same one? Usually when there’s one there’s many

Comment: I suggest aluminum foil to plug the mouse holes. Has worked for me with great success.

Comment: @Laura Sounds easy to do.

Comment: I've heard that plugging the hole with steel wool works well, too.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried various things in the past and have gradually refined my technique down to a two-pronged system:

Keep a pile of poison-bait somewhere where 1) your kids can't find it, 2) mice can find it, 3) it is easy for you to check, 4) it will keep dry. This is your "canary in a coal mine".

When the bait gets eaten by a mouse, you will know they are back. Refill the bait and set a trap near the bait. Use peanut-butter as the trap bait. Setting the trap is *very tricky* and takes a lot of practice to get right. Initially you will be giving them a free meal because they are very adept at taking the bait and not springing the trap.

Even when you don't catch them in the trap, they will still eat the poison. I've found that 3 to 4 meals is usually enough. You don't see the corpse but they stop coming back because they are dead somewhere.

I started with a live-capture trap. These work at least as well as the killer traps but you have to release the mouse somewhere and I soon got bored with that.

My method deals with the 1 or 2 mice that come into my house every year. If you already have a bigger problem than this, you may have to have a bigger solution. Look on Youtube and you will find some bulk-capture traps that seem really effective but you may have to build yourself.

Comment: **Very important:** also where your pets can't find it. You don't want to come home to a dead cat or dog.

Comment: @CJDennis Good point. I don't think any cat I've ever known would be rushing to make a meal of blue-coloured wheat grains, but I can see dogs thinking they look like an interesting snack.

Comment: I made a suggested edit to put that information in your answer, but it was rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Ultrasonic repellents do not work.  They are a scam.  (I know from experience, as well as online research.)

The third of the links that Chenmunka provided is the best of the three.

I have had a limited degree of success with various no-kill traps.  However, most of the mice I have removed from the house have caught themselves.  E.g. there's a bucket in the basement to catch water drips when it rains, and I found a mouse in there.  A number of times I have been in the bathroom and happened to arrive when there was a mouse there.  I closed the door.  There was no good place for him to hide, so after a few minutes I was able to catch him with a bucket.

In all cases where I have caught a mouse, I have driven them out to the local park.

Comment: Thank you for clearing the doubts regarding ultrasonic repellent. Wishing that the mouse will leave by himself, traps sound difficult.

Comment: @mohinip Also, make sure to keep food in mouse-proof containers.  Depending on how much stored food you have, this can be a chore, but it's worth it.

Comment: moved some food packets and could I identify the timings of entering and why it's been there.

Answer (score 0):

Kill the mice.

Use an oldschool mechanical mouse-trap (yes, they do work reasonably well) or use mouse-glue. (also works well, just make sure you do not forget about it, a rotting mouse carcass is nasty)